# Transmittance of one material through a multilayer

Tags: optics, optical-materials, photonics

Good morning,

I have the transmittance and the reflectance spectrum of **PET** (Polyethylene terephthalate) and I also have the transmittance and the reflectance spectrum of **PET + Copper** (50 nm). I would like to know if there is any way to get the transmittance and the reflectance spectrum only for the **Copper**?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you know what fraction of the copper and PET the incident light "sees", getting the reflectance spectra is possible.

$$R=\dfrac{\Phi_r}{\Phi_i}$$

Reflectance $R$ is defined as the fraction of incident radiant flux $\Phi_i$ that is reflected by the material and is wavelength-dependent. Let reflectance and transmittance spectra of copper and PET be $R_c(\lambda)$,$R_p(\lambda)$,$T_c(\lambda)$,$T_p(\lambda)$ respectively. If you shine $1\ W/m^2$ flux of  light with wavelength $\lambda$ through copper, you would get back $R_c(\lambda)\ W/m^2$ as reflected radiative flux.

Here you have a surface of area $ 1\ m^2$ and $F\ m^2$ of it is copper and $(1-F)\ m^2$ of it is PET. If you shine a flux of $1\ W/m^2$ on this surface, $F\ m^2$ copper would reflect $FR_c(\lambda)\:\text{Watts}$ and the $(1-F)\ m^2$ PET will reflect $(1-F)R_p(\lambda)\:\text{Watts}$, and so the total radiative flux is $FR_c(\lambda)+(1-F)R_p(\lambda)\ W/m^2$.

So by definition, the effective reflectance spectra of this composite material would be $$R_{eff}(\lambda)=FR_c(\lambda)+(1-F)R_p(\lambda)$$

Now I cannot extend this argument for the transmittance spectra, because then you have light going through the bulk of the sample and the calculation becomes a lot more tricky.